# Recovering Firefox's Saved Login Details

Tags: firefox, backup, transfer

I'm trying to log in as admin to a Joomla site of mine. I was really lazy and always relied on Firefox to remember my login info. I've recently had to replace the hard drive in my laptop. I bought an USB drive adaptor and manager to save all my music and files that weren't backed up after a week of transfer time.

I'm wondering if I can do the same thing with passwords and usernames that Firefox stores when you tell it to remember a password? If so, how exactly would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a Firefox question. Firefox stores passwords and usernames in a strict manner. You cannot just export and import it, it's confidential data.

If you used to save login details, you must've had a Firefox account (Sync). Please make use of that.

Otherwise, this website is of no help to you. There's no text file in some directory of Firefox which stores all your login details.

You might want to post this question in Firefox Support:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox